# How to use raw CUPS print queue?

Tags: printing

I have a laser printer connected to my Raspberry PI. Because the PI has such a puny CPU I have set it up as a raw printer. I am able to print just fine from my wife's mac, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it from my Ubuntu laptop. I am able to locate and install the printer, configured to use its PPD, on the laptop but the print output is garbage.

Any ideas on what I can do to troubleshoot this further?